# rendering with sdl_gfx is so slow , any alternative?

Tags: performance, opengl-es, rendering, sdl, gpu

I have been using sdl_gfx ( sdl2 extension library https://github.com/ferzkopp/SDL_gfx ) to make android games , i have always noticed that rendering primitives is so slow .
so i was rendering it once to a texture than drawing the texture on each frame to the screen ,but now im working on a game project in witch that method is not possible
i am looking for an alternative , is there a way to render primitives ( with alpha ) on android using sdl2 ?  a crossplatform method ( not gles ) .
sdl_gfx is fine but soooo slow ( double slow on android but even under windows so slow ) i think that's because it is using the sdl2 renderer to render to the screen , by calculating the pixels of the primitive and draw each pixel to the screen , so it is using the cpu not gpu ( software rendering ) , that makes it  so slow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at SDL_gpu to see if it fits your needs (disclaimer: I'm the author).  It uses OpenGL ES on Android and iOS (OpenGL on other platforms) directly and provides a few graphics features that SDL_Renderer is missing, like a shader API.  It also does a form of simple automatic batching to reduce OpenGL call overhead.

https://github.com/grimfang4/sdl-gpu

Comment: ofc dude i know about sdl_gpu , but i don't think it is bug free of as safe as sdl2 , i found some reported bugs of very basic functions such as drawing a circle !!

Comment: SDL2 does have more contributors and bugs do happen in all sorts of software as they mature, but I don't think a bug report that was closed over a year ago should really matter.  It's up to you though.  As far as I know, there is no other way to get fast primitive rendering with SDL2 unless you dive into GL (like I did already for SDL_gpu).

Comment: i didn't tell you that i already choosed sdl_gpu , and im using it now hh , plz give me the bug report email so i can report any problem to ask your help

Comment: You can find my contact info at dinomage.com.  The best place for bug reports is in the issue tracker on Github: https://github.com/grimfang4/sdl-gpu/issues

Comment: from the day you wrote me this answer i have been using sdl gpu each day for my engine , now i need your help and i posted on github but no one is there to answer